# Why do i get a select dropdown when in mobile view from superfish

Tags: theming, navigation

I have a navigation menu from superfish in the header for my site.  It looks fine in my regular desktop and even landscape view of tablets but when it gets down to the size of a phone the wheels kind of come off.  In the mobile view I still get the ususal three horizontal bars that expand into the dropdown menu. But a "select" element shows up for some reason.  I dont know what i changed because this doesnt show up in my original installation but in my dev sight it does.

Does anyone have any idea where this "select"  comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from a superfish plugin called `sf-smallscreen`.

You can either change it to kick in at a lower screen width, or you can disable it completely at `/admin/structure/block/manage/superfish/1/configure` -> Superfish Plugins -> SF-Smallscreen -> Disable